# How to slice ArrayIterator into two?

Tags: php

I've got this code

```
$second_half = $items; //ArrayIterator Object;
$first_half = array_slice($second_half ,0,ceil(count($second_half)/2));
```

This gives the warning **Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given**
Is there a way to slice an `ArrayIterator` object in two?

Basically I want one half of the unknown amount of items stored in `$first_half` and the remaining items `$second_half`; the result would be two `ArrayIterator` objects with two different sets of items.

Comment: Can you materialize it to an array first? An iterator generally has no concept of "length" and some are restricted to forward-only iteration. (I don't use PHP, but in all the languages I do use, this is *the required step* to divide "at half-way". If just needing "half in one array and half in the other", then just take one, put it here, take one, put it there, and repeat.)

Comment: @pst `ArrayIterator` implements the [`Countable` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php), which provides a `count` method, useful in determining length.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I am always amazed by PHP...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you can use the [`getArrayCopy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.getarraycopy.php) method of the ArrayIterator. This will return an array that you can then manipulate.

As for assigning one half of the results to a new `ArrayIterator`, and the other half to another `ArrayIterator`, you wouldn't need to reduce it to an array. You could simply use the `count` and `append` methods of the Iterator itself:

```
$group = new ArrayIterator;
$partA = new ArrayIterator;
$partB = new ArrayIterator;

$group->append( "Foo" );
$group->append( "Bar" );
$group->append( "Fiz" );
$group->append( "Buz" );
$group->append( "Tim" );

foreach ( $group as $key => $value ) {
  ( $key < ( $group->count() / 2 ) ) 
    ? $partA->append( $value ) 
    : $partB->append( $value );
}
```

This results in two new `ArrayIterator`'s being constructed:

```
ArrayIterator Object ( $partA )
(
    [0] => Foo
    [1] => Bar
    [2] => Fiz
)
ArrayIterator Object ( $partB )
(
    [0] => Buz
    [1] => Tim
)
```

Modify the ternary condition as needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
$first_half = new LimitIterator($items, 0, ceil(count($items) / 2));
$second_half = new LimitIterator($items, iterator_count($first_half));
```

This will get you 2 iterator which will allow you to only iterate over a half of the original `$items`.